# Change canvas background on embedded Bokeh bar chart

Tags: python, css, bokeh

I'm embedding a Bokeh bar chart on my website similar to [this bar chart](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html) from their example gallery

My website has a darker background so I'm trying to change the white background to a darker color that matches the rest of my template.

Setting the background of the plot area itself is not much of a problem as there are instructions [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/styling.html#background).

The entire canvas area is what I'm having problems with, see the white area on this picture, which I want to be able to change:
[image]

I tried all the css properties I could find, change the ones from the linked Bokeh css, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? The code should be identical to the one from the example gallery as far as changing the background.

Comment: The border is still part of the HTML canvas for the plot. You can set it separately: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/styling.html#border

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I missed that. I guess it being called border threw me off. Thanks a lot!